# Setting accepted language header in Capybara + Selenium + Chrome

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Capybara, Selenium and Chrome in my code and I just realized that the code is failing on machines with non-english locales (because Chrome is requesting the pages in different languages).

How can I force english as the only accepted language?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set profile preference thru options or dedicated profile class in driver registration:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['intl.accept_languages'] = 'en'

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, profile: profile, ...other)
```